# HTML 5 pattern not working for onclick event of button

Tags: html, validation

In a page, for getting field values I didn't use form tag, instead used Anchor tag's click event to get the values and used AJAX call to pass it to server.

Later tried out the HTML 5 pattern validation, it didn't work out; after so much try added form tag and then modified "anchor" to "button", then it worked.

***Old***

```
<div id="div1">
     <input type="text" id="message" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3}" required title="Enter valid Station" />
      <a id="add" onclick="addMessage();">Add</a>
</div>
```

***New***

```
 <form id="addMessage">
     <div id="div1">
         <input type="text" id="message" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3}" required title="Enter valid Station" />
          <button id="add">Add</button>
     </div>
 </form>
```

Is using a `form` tag and form submission the only way to trigger Pattern validation or are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a nice [overview of constraint validation in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/#toc-dom-api) on HTML5Rocks.

You can manually validate fields by calling the `checkValidity()` method on the DOM element in JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (document.getElementById('message').checkValidity()) {
    window.alert('valid station name');
    // addMessage();
  } else {
    window.alert('invalid station name!');
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <label>
    Station
    <input type="text" id="message" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3}" required title="Enter valid Station" maxlength="3">
  </label>
  <a id="add" role="button">Add</a>
</div>
```

And also for reference: [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Comment: Thanks, but instead of alert is there a way to trigger the tooltip error message?

Comment: The alert was just an example. There is a message stored in the `validationMessage` property that you can put into a tooltip, or elsewhere on the page if you wish.

Comment: It looks like setCustomValidity(''); can be used trigger tooltip.

Comment: Thanks for the great info, even though I came across the html5rocks article long back, I hadn't read html5rock's article completely.. my bad.